# Does a regular expression model the empty language if it contains symbols not in the alphabet?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Suppose $\Sigma = \{ a,b \}$ and the regular expression $(a^*b+dc)^*(b^*d + ad)^*$. Is it equal to $\varnothing$?

So I have a regular expression like this: $(a^*b+dc)^*$. As only $(a,b) \in \Sigma$, I see that:

- $dc=\varnothing$

So $(a^*b+dc)^*=(a^*b)^*$.

Then:

- $(b^*d + ad)^* = (\varnothing + \varnothing)^*=(\varnothing)^*$ and as $(\varnothing)^*=\epsilon$, $(b^*d + ad)^*$ becomes $\epsilon$.

So my regular expression is simply $ (a^*b)^*$? Am I correct, or does the fact that the regular expression contain at least one symbol not in alphabet make it wrong immediately?

Comment: I hope nobody posed this as homework question.

Comment: @Raphael I found this question in a book, that has no correction. But can you explain why you react in such way?

Comment: @JohnMayne Because the answer is, essentially, "That's an invalid question." It's fine for somebody to ask the question when they don't understand that the given regular expression is invalid. However, for somebody who _does_ understand to ask that question as an exercise (i.e., to ask it to somebody who probably doesn't understand) is unfair and confusing. It's essentially a trick question that's likely to make people think they don't understand. To re-use the example from my answer, it's like asking a seven-year-old, "What's seventy-red plus four?" Now the kid is just confused.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's basically what has been done to me. And I got really confused because of this.

Comment: Exactly, and you shouldn't have been. This is a non-issue, essentially. Fully agreed with @DavidRicherby. John, in which book did you find this? I want to put it on my red-flag list.

Comment: @Raphael No idea. My teacher gave me a photocopy of one of the pages of the book. And the book is in French. So, sorry, can't help you with that. But keep in mind, that in the French educational system, it is pretty common to test students by confusing them. The teachers themselves tend to get confused over what was really asked even during an EXAM.

Comment: @JohnMayne 1) You should ask your teacher where the pages are taken from (they have to give attribution!) and if they intended to confuse their students. You can also point them here. 2) I hope that this is not the case in the French system as a whole but rather a failing of individual teachers or maybe schools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regular expressions only use characters from the alphabet so, if you've fixed your alphabet to be $\{a,b\}$, then $(a^∗b+dc)^∗(b^∗d+ad)^∗$ isn't a regular expression. It doesn't describe any language, in just the same way that "seventy red" doesn't describe any number. In particular, it doesn't describe the empty language, in the same way that "seventy red" isn't equal to zero.

Now, if your alphabet includes all the symbols $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, you might want to ask what are the strings in $L((a^∗b+dc)^∗(b^∗d+ad)^∗)$ that contain only $a$'s and $b$'s. That is, what is $L((a^∗b+dc)^∗(b^∗d+ad)^∗)\cap \{a,b\}^*$? And the answer to that is that it's all strings matching $(a^*b)^*$, as you derive in the question.

**Appendix.** One could attempt to sidestep these issues by redefining regular expressions in a way that gives them well-defined semantics if they include symbols not in the alphabet. However, the standard definition does not do this.

Indeed, trying to do so would seem to open up a huge can of worms. For example, suppose your alphabet is $\{a,b\}$. We could agree that, since $c$ is not a symbol in the alphabet, the regular-expression-like-object $abc$ matches nothing. OK, but $+$ is also a symbol that's not in the alphabet. Maybe you're happy with $ab+$ matching nothing because it's syntactically invalid – note, $ab+$, not $ab^+$! But, now, what does $a+b$ match? Does it mean "$a$ or $b$" or "$a$ followed by some symbol that's not in the alphabet followed by $b$, which is impossible, so it matches nothing"?

Comment: Perfect answer. Everything has been clarified to me. Thank you.

Comment: We should probably account for somebody defining an interpretation/semantics of regular expressions that deals with "missing symbols" in a well-defined way.

Comment: $(a^*b)^*$ wouldn't be equivalent to $(a+b)^*$; it would be equivalent to $\varepsilon+(a+b)^*b$, if I can remember the notation for this.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Good catch -- thanks! I just deleted that claim -- it seems reasonable to say "Your regular expression is equivalent to this simpler one" but "Your regular expression is equivalent to this more complicated one" doesn't add anything.

Comment: If you want to take the sidestep seriously, of course you would prohibit "reserved" symbols.